# meromorphic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(z)$ and $F(z,\theta)$ be complex function with $z,\theta \in \mathbb{C} $ . Suppose that for $\theta $ real $F(z)=F(z,\theta)$.
Now suppose that for $A,B \subset \mathbb{C},F(z,\theta)$ can be  meromorphically continued in z from $A$ to $B$.

How to proof that $F(z)$ can be meromorphically continued   from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: What is there to prove?  If $F(z) = F(z, \theta)$ (for some particular $\theta$), and $F(z,\theta)$ can be ..., then that says $F(z)$ can be ...

Comment: In a book they say this is true by the identity principle for meromorphic functions. what is the the identity principle for meromorphic functions?

Comment: This question seems to not be worded correctly as Robert Israel points out, but I presume the answer is supposed to be that you note we can analytically continue for all real theta, and the real line has an accumulation point so we conclude by the principle of analytic (resp. meromorphic) continuation